# My try to write unix domain socket communication script between Ruby and C

Tags: c, ruby, sockets, unix, unix-socket

I am trying to make a bridge via unix domain socket between Ruby script as server and C app as client but currently I am stuck in the read loop until I kill Ruby script maybe someone could look at the code?

```
    struct sockaddr_un addr;
  int fd,rc;
  char *socket_path = "/tmp/auth.sock";

  char *output_packet = cern_format_packet(pw, key);


  if ( (fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
    error("socket error");
    return 0;
  }

  memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
  addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
  strncpy(addr.sun_path, socket_path, sizeof(addr.sun_path)-1);

  if (connect(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1) {
    error("connect error");
    return 0;
  }
  logit("cern_output: %s", output_packet);
  write(fd, output_packet, strlen(output_packet));

#define BUFFERSIZE 1024
#define MAXDATASIZE 256   
  int c, q = 0, success;
  char* input_buffer;
  char data_buffer[MAXDATASIZE];
  size_t input_buffer_size = BUFFERSIZE;
  input_buffer = malloc(input_buffer_size);

  if (input_buffer)
  {
      while((c = read(fd, data_buffer, MAXDATASIZE)) > 0)
      {
          if (c + q > input_buffer_size)
          {
              input_buffer_size *= 2; /* Arbitrary doubling of size. */
              char* tmp = realloc(input_buffer, input_buffer_size);
              if (tmp)
              {
                  input_buffer = tmp;
              }
              else
              {
                  /* memory allocation failure. */
                  free(input_buffer);
                  input_buffer = 0;
                  break;
              }
          }
          memcpy(input_buffer + q, data_buffer, c);
          q += c;
      }
  }
  json_error_t error; 
  json_t *root = json_loads( input_buffer, 0, &error );
  if (root) {
    json_t *json_status = json_object_get( root, "status" );
    json_t *json_command = json_object_get( root, "command" );
    const char *return_comamnd = json_string_value( json_command );
    success = (int)json_integer_value(json_status);
    logit("json_response: status: %i command: %s",success, return_comamnd);
  }


  close(fd);
  return success;
```

And the ruby script

```
require "socket"
require 'msgpack'
require "json"

file = "/tmp/auth.sock"

File.unlink if File.exists?(file) && File.socket?(file)

serv = UNIXServer.new(file)

loop do
        s = serv.accept
        msg = s.gets
        msg = msg.gsub("\n", "") if msg
        p JSON.parse(msg)
        a = {}
        a["status"] = 1
        a["command"] = "hello world"
        s.write(JSON.generate(a))
s.close
end
```

Comment: I think the problem is with the ruby script because in while cycle it doesn't get anything to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client's call to `read()` most likely blocks because the server did send less then the client was told to read, that is `MAXDATASIZE` bytes.

Do get around this let the server orderly shutdown the socket before closing it.

I'm no Ruby expert but may be something like:

```
s.shutdown
s.close
```

would do the job.

---

Also in the server this line:

```
msg = s.gets
```

might block until a `\n` had been received. (See here for details on `gets`: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-i-gets)

Comment: Changed to 8 but no luck still stuck... :(

Comment: @AurimasNiekis: For testing try `1`. And `printf()` what had been received by each call to `read()`.

Comment: I added debug info around the all the code and it stucks inside the while loop and dont even cycle

Comment: @AurimasNiekis: It stucks inside the 1st call to `read()`, with `read()` being told to read exactly `1` byte?

Comment: Yes, it even not enter the cycle inside

Comment: In the client: You might like to add code to test whether the earlier call to `write()` had been successful. Also `write()` out a final `\n` after this one call to `wite()` you already have. Please see my updated answer.